# PHP BCrypt output correct?

Tags: php, security, salt, bcrypt, password-hash

New to stackoverflow :)

I just now started to use a bcrypt function I've found on some site about security. I've never really worried about the output from this until our technician at work said this to me:

> The salt seems to always be in the front of every password.

Is this correct or have I made a major boo boo? :)

The code I use is this:

```
<?php
function bcrypt($password, $salt, $rounds=12) {
    // Check if bcrypt is available on the server
    if (CRYPT_BLOWFISH != 1) {
        throw new Exception("bcrypt stöds inte. Se http://php.net/crypt");
        return;
    }

    // Check that rounds are within the allowed range
    if ($rounds < 4)
        $rounds = 4;
    else if ($rounds > 12) 
        $rounds = 12;

    // Create a prefix to tell the crypt that we want to use bcrypt
    $salt_prefix = sprintf('$2a$%02d$', $rounds);

    // Check if the salt contains invalid characters:
    if (!preg_match('#^[A-Za-z0-9./]{22}$#', $salt)) {

        // The salt is not bcrypt-safe. Redo to 22 characters (A-Za-z0-9. /)
        $new_salt = base64_encode($salt);

        if (strlen($new_salt) < 22)

            $new_salt .= base64_encode(md5($salt));
            $salt = substr($new_salt, 0, 22);
            $salt = str_replace(array('+', '-'), '.', $salt);    
            $salt = str_replace(array('=', '_'), '/', $salt);
    }

    // hash the password with bcrypt
    return crypt($password, $salt_prefix.$salt);
 }

 // Examples :
 echo "Bcrypt: ". bcrypt('abc', 'QyrjMQfjgGIb4ymtdKQXIr', 12);
?>
```

This will output:

```
Bcrypt: $2a$12$QyrjMQfjgGIb4ymtdKQXIewDBqhA3eNppF8qOrMhidnEbzNvmHqhy
```

As you can see the salt is inside the password now "bold text":

Salt = **`QyrjMQfjgGIb4ymtdKQXIr`**

pass = *$2a$12$***`QyrjMQfjgGIb4ymtdKQXI`**

*ewDBqhA3eNppF8qOrMhidnEbzNvmHqhy*

This seem to be the same every time regardless of salt. Salt is always included except the last character?

Comment: The answer to your question can be found here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037271/the-point-with-the-salt-in-bcrypt

Comment: Please use [this library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) instead of rolling your own. PHP has strong and simple password hash functions since version 5.5, and this library backports them starting with PHP 5.3.7. Also please note that this library tries to mitigate timing attacks by always comparing the WHOLE string, and not stop upon the first difference. Bottom line: Simply use it.

Comment: Regarding the salt’s length: [Length of salt in CRYPT_BLOWFISH](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15727563/53114)

Comment: thanks for the really fast answers :) Now I know a little more. I will check out the library. But as I understand it the output is correct?. I do have to use random salts of course.

Comment: Hi, please avoid `<br/>` tags for formatting, and avoid quote devices `>` for your code. Posts can be (and often are) edited/improved here by higher-rep readers, and either of those make it hard work. Use paragraphs and four-space indents (code button) instead. Thanks!

Comment: No probs, welcome to the site!

Comment: Just to answer your question: yes it is correct that the salt is part of the resulting hash string, and it is ok that it is plaintext. This salt is necessary for verifying the password later.

Answer (score 0):

You can test an existing bcrypt hash with lots of tools online, like this [bcrypt generator](https://www.bcrypt-generator.com)